# How do I find ALL the positions of the lowest numbers in a list? (python)

Tags: python, for-loop

The following code below returns the position of the first lowest number in a list.

```
xy = [50, 2, 34, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 10 ,1] 
t=0
for i in range(len(xy)):
    if xy[i]<xy[t]:        
        t=i
print(t)

out: 6
```

I would like to get the positions of all the lowest numbers. In this case it should be 6,9,11. How do I go about in base Python?

Comment: Yep, just realized that @davedwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Python's predefined `min` function to get the minimum value in the list, then get the indices of the values equal to that minimum using a list comprehension, like this:

```
xy = [50, 2, 34, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 10 ,1]
lowest = min(xy)
positions = [i for i, v in enumerate(xy) if v == lowest]
print(positions) # ==> [6, 9, 11]
```

Comment: Doesn't this work only because there are 3 ones in the list? Suppose the other two ones were removed. This code does not then update the lowest value. It will only give the locations of the single minimum value. I guess I am interpreting the question as "the three lowest numbers".

Comment: @user5179531 I think the OP just didn't phrase his questions very well, I think he wants the positions of the minimum value, because he didn't mention three, it's three just because there are three ones. Not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

This should be the most CPU efficient solution because it runs the list only once. @Mr Geek's solution should be slightly better on memory because his way only produces one list of results.

```
xy = [50, 2, 34, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 10 ,1]
min_val = sys.maxsize
result = []
for index, num in enumerate(xy):
  if num < min_val:
    min_val = num
    result = [index]
  elif num == min_val:
    result.append(index)
```

result now contains `[6, 9, 11]`

Whenever we find a new minimum value, we clear the list of results and add the new number. Whenever we find the same number, we add it to the list.